# Do the Doom Bots of Doom have Hidden Bonuses?

Tags: league-of-legends

So the new Coop-vs-AI Modus Doom Bots of Doom lets you play against "Unfair" Bots. All of them have enhanced abilities and after the second difficulty they also have Weird Passives (Seriously who the hell thinks that Swain ultimate makes a good passive??).

Now while most of the Additional Spells are shown in-game or at least in the patch notes (Additional champion abilities, Passives and Dragon-Teleport) I sometimes feel like the bots Have some extra Bonuses.

The 2 main things that come to my mind are: Better Scalings and More gold. I'm not 100% sure and I don't really have a source on this but I feel like the bots scale better with AP/AD and I also feel like they get more gold than the players (The bots farm is pretty crappy but they still manage to keep up in items somehow).

Are there any things like more damage, more gold or more resistance that aren't described in-game or in the patch notes that apply to these Bots?

Comment: I can confirm that they earn about 25 gold per 5 -10 seconds

Comment: wtf is boni? I've never seen this term

Comment: @Ender Oh sorry I just looked up the dictionary. In English it should be bonuses... Boni is the original latin or german plural.

Comment: Actually all bots have a "hidden" passive for gold generation, if you play the normal coop vs ai game you can see that even if you have denied almost all farm from a bot and he doesnt have a kill he will finish his itens anyway.

Answer (score 1):

most of the abilities you are looking for are described here, usually it's a mix of passives that you don't see at start, other than the normal co-op vs ai cheats (which i could not document): http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Doom_Bots_of_Doom
hope this helps

Comment: I've already read the wiki article and the cheating article. Both of them show no information about whether the bots have additional advantages/gold or not.

Comment: @jutschge should include that information in your question. Which will make this one not useful.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I included it. The things you find in the wiki article are also written down in the patch notes and the cheating article has absolutely nothing to do with League (or at least there is no relevant information to this question). Anyone who read these 2 articles and my question should be able to realise this.

Comment: I see in-game and patch notes, no reference to the wiki. Regardless, adding the links to all the current information sources wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: here you go, sorry you didn't find this useful my only other option would be to hack the gamefiles for client information strings but that takes time and doom bots aren't here to stay: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Co-op_vs._AI ... my answer is still the same though and i think it is relevant even without the exact stats, nobody knows the exact mechanic of co-op but the doom bots are just an addon of functionality on top of what was already there. also, what oscar said is available here: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Co-op_vs._AI